# WebConfigurationManager.Save() Causes Values In External Config File To Be Written To Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings, web.config-transform

I have a ASP.NET app that needs to update a an AppSetting value (Shown as UPDATETHIS below) in the web.config. Which is working fine...

Method

```
    public static bool UpdateAppSetting(string name, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
            config.AppSettings.Settings[name].Value = value;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```
  <appSettings file="custom.config">
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UPDATETHIS" value="1.6" />
  </appSettings>
```

However... As you can see I have a custom.config file which has other custom AppSettings within in.

When I update the value of '**UPDATETHIS**' to say '**1.7**' it updates fine BUT it takes all the settings in custom.config and writes/saves those to the web.config as well as the new updated value!?

It seems I can't just update that single value and have a custom appsettings config? Anyone else know how to get around this?

Comment: I've had the same issue. I don't think there is a workaround. Finally removed my custom.config and now keep all settings in the web.config and it's better because if you change something in web.config the app will restart automatically with new settings, but if you change your custom.config nothing will happen.